# How to give your layout a border title?

Tags: android, border

I have a `Relative Layout` whom I want to give a titled border like this. I know how to create a border using drawable but not border with title.

[image]

This is code for layout not for titled border.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/matchNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="@string/matches"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Runs:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wicket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/totalWickets"
        android:text="Wickets:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, how can I add a titled border.

Answer (score 2):

Try below xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_corner_with_shadow"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp12"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

               //Add your content here

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp16"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dp8"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp18"
                android:text="Your Title"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Drawable
**shape_rounded_corner_with_shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: It works fine but the problem is the border overlaps the title. So, what should I do?

Comment: please share screenshot.